# How to add a sequence to a field in the account.invoice model?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to add a sequence to one field called x_id_proforma in the account.invoice model when a invoice passes to PRO -FORMA. But the problem is that it does not assign the sequence to x_id_proforma field when I press the PRO -FORMA button.

This is the button that is in the view:

```
<button name="invoice_proforma2" states="draft" string="PRO-FORMA" groups="account.group_proforma_invoices"/>
```

This is my invoice.py :

```
@api.multi
def invoice_prsoforma2(self, vals):
    for invoice in self: 
        invoice.x_id_proforma = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('account.invoice') 
    return super(AccountInvoice, self).invoice_proforma2(vals)
```

What I want is that when you press the PRO -FORMA the field button is assigned the sequence to field x_id.proforma.

This view is customer invoices:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have define wrong function name. Try with below code

```
@api.multi
def invoice_proforma2(self, vals):
    for invoice in self: 
        invoice.x_id_proforma = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('account.invoice') 
    return super(AccountInvoice, self).invoice_proforma2(vals)
```

NOTE:

Print `invoice` variable and check weather function is call or not.